# Cannot ZIP craft folder - WINDOWS

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

I've come across not a deal breaking problem - but an issue that will cost allot of time.

When I try to compress the craft folder (so I can upload it to a server) using windows:

Send to >> compressor >> I am given an error:

[image]

"File not found or no permission"

[image]

I did a bit of looking around and re-ran the compressor on win-zip - this allowed all but the files in `VENDOR/BIN` to be compressed so I would assume the problem is lying there.

[image]

So my question is -

Why is there a permission error here?
And are these files required (as in, do these files carry anything vital to craft)

Feel free to ask any follow up questions you might have if you need calcification, I will be happy to answer.

Side note - I am doing this to avoid using FTP - as FTP uploading/downloading a craft site is taking around an HOUR and its lost time I cannot justify.

Thanks in advance -
Wally

Comment: You could try stopping the web server, or copying all files and folders to a temporary folder and compressing them there.

Comment: Hi Mato - So am I correct in thinking that you believe that the bin folder is being used by another program/server which is causing the issue? Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: Worth a try. Or you could try opening Explorer with Admin rights and then compressing/copying files.